# Is it possible for Firestore to generate the same uid when registering a user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have my backend hosted in firebase. Whenever a new user registers I create a new account in my firestore collection. Each user will be identified by a unique uid generated by firebase. Is it possible with enough users to generate the same uid and hence write over another user's data when registering? Or does firestore have any built-in measures to prevent this from happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Auth guarantees that each user will have a truly unique ID within your project.  There is nothing you have to do.  Just accept the UID it generates.